# US Expatriate, do I have to file for an extension, or do I automatically get it, as in without doing anything?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax

This is my 1st time abroad for a long time, and according to the [IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/U.S.-Citizens-and-Resident-Aliens-Abroad---Automatic-2-Month-Extension-of-Time-to-File):

"You may be allowed an automatic 2-month extension of time to file your return and pay any federal income tax that is due. You will be allowed the extension if you are a U.S. citizen..." and are living/conducting business abroad at the time of taxes.

This applies to me, but what exactly does "automatic" mean: does it mean I can sit around and do nothing, and I will get the extension? Or does it mean I am entitled to an extension but still need to file some form? If so what form do I file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The cited page also says: "**How To Get The Extension** To use this automatic 2-month extension, you must attach a statement to your return explaining which of the two situations listed earlier qualified you for the extension."

Comment: @PeteBecker aha, so I would fine late, and at that time simply attach a statement?

Comment: @PeteBecker it also mentions an interest rate, do you know what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The 2 months extension is automatic, you just need to tell them that you're using it by attaching a statement to the return, as Pete Becker mentioned in the comments.

From [the IRS pub 54](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p54/ch01.html#en_US_2015_publink100047323):

> **How to get the extension**.   To use this automatic 2-month extension, you must attach a statement to your return explaining which of the two situations listed earlier qualified you for the extension.

The "regular" 6 months extension though is granted automatically, *upon request*, so if you cannot make it by June deadline you should file the form 4868 to request a further extension.

> **Automatic 6-month extension**.   If you are not able to file your return by the due date, you generally can get an automatic 6-month extension of time to file (but not of time to pay). To get this automatic extension, you must file a paper Form 4868 or use IRS e-file (electronic filing). For more information about filing electronically, see E-file options , later.

Keep in mind that the due date is still April 15th (18th this year), so the 6-month extension pushes it back to October.

> **Previous 2-month extension**.   If you cannot file your return within the automatic 2-month extension period, you generally can get an additional 4 months to file your return, for a total of 6 months. The 2-month period and the 6-month period start at the same time. You have to request the additional 4 months by the new due date allowed by the 2-month extension.

You can ask an additional 2 months extension (this is no longer automatic) to push it further to December. See the publication.

These are extension **to file**, not to pay. With the form 4868 you're also expected to submit a payment that will cover your tax liability (at least in the ballpark).

The interest is pretty low (less than 1% right now), but there's also a penalty which may be pretty substantial if you don't pay enough by the due date. See [the IRS tax topic 301](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc306.html). There are "safe harbor" rules to avoid the penalty.